# Pug image as a link

Tags: node.js, pug

how do you make an  image a link in Pug I've tried

```
   a(href='https://github.com/LouieAdamian') img(src="/img/GitHub.png")
```

and

```
img(src="/img/GitHub.png")
a(href='https://github.com/LouieAdamian')
```

and

```
a(href='https://github.com/LouieAdamian')
img(src="/img/GitHub.png")
```

none of these worked I ether ended up with the text `img(src="/img/GitHub.png")` as the link or no link at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This way *(the indent is necessary)*:

```
a(href='https://github.com/LouieAdamian')
  img(src="/img/GitHub.png")
```